# Why Does Moving My Function To A Different File Increase Webpage Size by 50%? (Webpack, Next, ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a simple function in my component which is almost identical to:

```js
import SomeComponent from '../components/some_component';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {someFakeUtil} from '../util';

const REQUIRED_COMPONENTS = {SomeComponent};

function myComponent({jsxString}){
    const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
    function renderJsx(s) {
        // It would be nice to move this function to .util, 
        // but doing so increases the page size by 50kb somehow, which is 50% bigger 
        for(var componentName in REQUIRED_COMPONENTS) {
            window[componentName] = REQUIRED_COMPONENTS[componentName];
        }
        return eval(s)
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        setContent(renderJsx(jsxString))
    }, [])

    return (<div>{content}</div>);
}
```

This works well and when I build my page for production the page size ends up at about 100kb.

For Code cleanliness reasons, I would like to move the renderJsx function to my utility js file. Notice that I previously was already importing some functions from `util.js`;

When I do this:

```js
//util.js
import SomeComponent from '../components/some_component'
const REQUIRED_COMPONENTS = {SomeComponent};
export function renderJsx(s) {
    // It would be nice to move this function to .util, 
    // but doing so increases the page size by 50kb somehow, which is 50% bigger 
    for(var componentName in REQUIRED_COMPONENTS) {
        window[componentName] = REQUIRED_COMPONENTS[componentName];
    }
    return eval(s)
}

export function someFakeUtil() {
    // This was already being imported before the change to move renderJsx to util.js
    ...
}
```

And then my new component:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {someFakeUtil, renderJsx} from '../util';

function myComponent({jsxString}){
    const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        setContent(renderJsx(jsxString))
    }, [])

    return (<div>{content}</div>);
}
```

My page size increases by a massive 50kb simply for moving the function to a new .js file! A file that I was already importing from nonetheless, and that file itself is less than 50 lines of code total. It doesn't seem to make sense why such a drastic increase in file size would occur. Why would this happen?

I'm using next.js and the default webpack config, building with `npx next build`.